# No puedo cambiar JDK Location en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Buenos días. He instalado la ultima versión de Android Studio, esto es la 2.3.2 y cuando intento cambiar la JDK location, no me deja. Es decir la cambio pero cuando le doy a apply vuelve a lo que había. Tengo colocada la dirección en la variable de entorno. pero no hay forma, con lo cual me sigue apareciendo el clásico error 216. Estoy utilizando Windows 10 y hasta ahora con otras versiones de Android Studio me ha funcionado correctamente.
Puede alguien indicarme que hago mal?
Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Presiona <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> para abrir la ventana de Project Structure o ***File > Project Structure > [Platform Settings] > SDKs***, alli tienes para modificar la ruta a tu `JDK`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Edito:
Prueba de la siguiente manera:

1º Abre la ruta **C:\Users\USUARIO\.AndroidStudioX.X\config** (unicamente teniendo en cuenta el nombre de usuario y donde X.X la version de tu Android Studio)

2º Abre la carpeta **options** y localiza el archivo **jdk.table.xml**

3aº Haz una copia de éste y eliminalo.

3bº Haz una copia de éste, abrelo y modifica la version del `JDK`.

4º Reinicia Android Studio en caso de tenerlo abierto

Comment: Hola Israel. Eso ya lo hago, pero cuando lo valido vuelve a salir lo que había. No me deja cambiarlo. Ahora he visto que cuando busco la dirección en el ordenador, el directorio C me aparece con un puequeño candado. Supongo que por eso no me deja cambiar el JDK location.

Comment: Hola Israel. Eso ya lo hago. Lo que ocurre es que cuando lo valido no me lo cambia y vuelve a quedar como estaba. Ahora he visto que cuando le doy a buscar la dirección de java en la carpeta C del mi ordenata me aperece un pequeño candado. Posiblemente por eso no me deja cambiar la JDK location. Ahora tengo que averiguar como quitar el dichoso candado en Windows 10.

Comment: Edito mi respuesta agregando una posible solución. En el paso 3, tienes dos opciones, la mas sencilla es eliminar el archivo haciendo una copia de éste antes por si es necesario restaurarlo en caso de no funcionar.

Comment: No hay manera Israel. Hago todo lo que me indicas pero no me deja cambiarlo. El candado solo me aparece cuando busco la direccion de jdk con el android studio. Es decir que en explorador de windows no aparece ningun candado. Puede que sea cosa de Android. Ya no sé por donde ando. Seguro que mis 78 años me están volviendo tonto. je,je

Comment: Si te refieres a este candado http://prntscr.com/ffqeuh es normal, aparece siempre. Si pones la carpeta del JKD en el escritorio por ejemplo, desmarcas la casilla de Used embedded JDK y pones la ruta del JDK en el escritorio, sigue revertiendose ?

Comment: Si, es ese candado. Desmarco la casilla y pongo la ruta pero sigue revertiendose.

Comment: Me dejas descolocado, el candado es normal, a mi me sale también. He descargado un JDK y me lo ha cambiado sin mayor problema. Si no funciona lo que he mencionado anteriormente, lo único que se me ocurre es que hagas el paso de eliminar el archivo, manteniendo android studio abierto, y  coloques la ruta del JDK sin reiniciarlo para evitar que compruebe si tenias antes alguna ruta especificada.

Comment: Voy a comer. Luego pruebo lo que me dices y te comento. Saludos

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59871/discussion-between-abuelo-and-israel).

Comment: Hola Israel. Estoy asombrado. He instalado la version 2.1.3 de Android Studio y sin tocar nada ya me aparece el JDK location correcto.

Comment: Si instalas de nuevo la 2.3.2 entonces deberia mantener el JDK cuando seleccionas que quieres importar la configuracion de un android studio anterior.

Comment: Hola. Eso es lo que voy a hacer. Update new version e importar configuracion del anterior. Ya te contaré que tal vá.